# Libgdx Combine more than 2 sprite arrays into 1 sprite array

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

I was wondering if theirs a way to combine more than 2 sprite arrays into 1 sprite array. For example, I want to combine these 4 arrays of card suits into 1 array. (Arrays from com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array)

```
public class Diamonds extends CardTypes {
public Array<Sprite> diamonds = new Array<Sprite>();

public void cards(){
    diamonds.add(ace = new Sprite(new Texture("diamonds/AD.png")));
    diamonds.add(two = new Sprite(new Texture("diamonds/2D.png")));
    diamonds.add(three = new Sprite(new Texture("diamonds/3D.png")));}}

public class Spades extends CardTypes{
        public Array<Sprite> spades = new Array<Sprite>();

    public void cards(){
        spades.add(ace = new Sprite(new Texture("spades/AS.png")));
        spades.add(two = new Sprite(new Texture("spades/2S.png")));
        spades.add(three = new Sprite(new Texture("spades/3S.png")));}}

public class Clubs extends CardTypes {
public Array<Sprite> clubs = new Array<Sprite>();

public void cards(){
    clubs.add(ace = new Sprite(new Texture("clubs/AC.png")));
    clubs.add(two = new Sprite(new Texture("clubs/2C.png")));
    clubs.add(three = new Sprite(new Texture("clubs/3C.png")));}}

public class Hearts extends CardTypes {
public Array<Sprite> hearts = new Array<Sprite>();

public void cards(){
    hearts.add(ace = new Sprite(new Texture("hearts/AH.png")));
    hearts.add(two = new Sprite(new Texture("hearts/2H.png")));
    hearts.add(three = new Sprite(new Texture("hearts/3H.png")));}}
```

Each of these sprite arrays holds 3 cards and I tried creating a different sprite array and use the addAll() method from com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: What is your code, what are your inputs, and what do you expect ?

Comment: I just want to know how to combine these 4 separate arrays into 1 array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create object and Keep reference of all your `CardTypes`

```
Diamonds diamond= new Diamond();
diamond.cards();                 // add sprites into diamonds array

Spades spade = new Spades();
spade.cards();

Clubs club=new Club();
club.cards();

Hearts heart=new Hearts();
heart.cards();
```

Now combine all cards in one `Array` :

```
Array allCard = new Array<Sprite>();
allCard.addAll(diamond.diamonds);
allCard.addAll(spade.spades);
allCard.addAll(club.clubs);
allCard.addAll(heart.hearts);
```